# I ejected SD card through phone before factory resetting BUT card is empty. How can I recover this?

Tags: external-sd, factory-reset, motorola-moto-g, motorola-moto-g3

Just before I factory reset my Motorola G3 I pressed “eject SD card” through the settings. (I didn’t remove the card from the phone though) Now everything the from SD card (media/photos) are gone. What happened and how can I recover this?!

PS. I used it as a portable storage, not internal. Also, I didn’t even get the option of deleting the SD card.

Please help.

Comment: insert in card reader and recover on pc with any recovery software

Comment: @alecxs Aren't sd cards encrypted a little bit as they are first formatted on Android?

Comment: try [Zero Assumption Recovery](http://www.z-a-recovery.com) or [GetDataBack for FAT](http://www.runtime.org)