# Photos made this afternoon disappeared after I rebooted phone - how to recover them?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, photos, reboot

This morning, since the memory of the internal storage reached its limit, I moved all the pics in the Camera album to the SD card. In the afternoon, I took a couple of pics which if I remember correctly were stored by default in the same album Camera (in the SD) in which I moved the other pictures in the morning. I checked them on the way home and they were still there. At some point, I wanted to edit one of the new ones but it kept giving me errors (no connection and "you can edit only pics larger than 50 x 50 pixels"- and I was surprised since they are always larger than that!).
I rebooted my phone, and when I opened the gallery the pics taken in the afternoon were gone (not to consider how many pics got corrupted among the ones I moved in the morning). I took other pictures, still ended up in the Camera folder (in the SD!), still editing error. I rebooted again, and they disappeared again.

Even weirder, after some time a retook some pics and these were saved in the Camera folder in the internal storage (Not in Camera SD!), and they are not disappearing anymore.

I already tried re-inserting SD. What can I do?

Comment: guesswork: if not the MicroSD Card itself is corrupt, probably the app used for moving did not notice that it didn't had permission for MicroSD Card, so the pictures where moved into nowhere. remaining thumbnails where refreshed and disappeared from gallery on reboot

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/233669